# kivy buildozer cant compile application targeting python3

Tags: android, python, kivy, buildozer

I'm trying to build my kivy application against python3.

First I downloaded the crystax ndk, and set the ANDROIDNDK to it's location. I added python3crystax to my requirements in the buildozer.spec and launched the build with:

> buildozer android debug deploy run logcat

This command results in the following error:

> Command failed: pip install --target=/home/cedric/Documents/Development/python/kivyapp/.buildozer/applibs python3crystax

If I try to install python3crystax manually with pip it seems, that this package dosen't even exists?

trying it with

> buildozer android debug deploy run logcat

causes the following error:

> ERROR: The colorama Python module could not be found, please install
>   version 0.3.3 or higher
>
> ERROR: The appdirs Python module could not be found, please install
>   it.
>
> ERROR: The sh Python module could not be found, please install version
>   1.10 or higher
>
> ERROR: The jinja2 Python module could not be found, please install it.

All modules are installed with their current version.
Can anybody help me to solve this problem?

Thanks Cedric

Answer (score 3):

Use `buildozer android_new debug` instead, you are using `android` which builds with the old toolchain and does not support python3.