# Can't build Kivy project with buildozer and python3crystax

Tags: android, python-3.x, kivy, buildozer

Sorry for possible stupid question, but today I spent ~5 hours trying to build simple apk with Python3, Buildozer and Crystax NDK. I used Buildozer VM, downloaded Crystax ndk 10.3.2, created buildozer.spec as follow on github instruction https://github.com/kivy/buildozer . My buildozer.spec:

```
title = Cyba app
package.name = cyapp
package.domain = ru.longint
source.dir = .
requirements = python3crystax,kivy
android.ndk_path = ~/.buildozer/crystax-ndk
```

and few others.
When I run `buildozer -v android debug` to make first compilation (by the instruction on the Buildozer's wiki), I got next logs:

```
# Check configuration tokens
# Ensure build layout
# Check configuration tokens
# Preparing build
# Check requirements for android
# Run 'dpkg --version'
# Cwd None
Debian 'dpkg' package management program version 1.18.10 (amd64).
This is free software; see the GNU General Public License version 2 or
later for copying conditions. There is NO warranty.
# Search for Git (git)
#  -> found at /usr/bin/git
# Search for Cython (cython)
#  -> found at /usr/local/bin/cython
# Search for Java compiler (javac)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
# Search for Java keytool (keytool)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/keytool
# Install platform
# Apache ANT found at /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4
# Android SDK found at /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20
# Android NDK found at /home/kivy/.buildozer/crystax-ndk
# Check application requirements
# Run './distribute.sh -l'
# Cwd /home/kivy/Documents/kbs/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
Available modules: android apsw audiostream bidi boost cherrypy c_igraph click cprotobuf cymunk django docutils ecdsa enum34 evdev ffmpeg ffmpeg2 ffpyplayer ffpyplayer_tito flask freetype gevent greenlet harfbuzz hostpython igraph itsdangerous jinja2 jpeg kivent_core kivent_cymunk kivy leveldb libevent libpq libsodium libswift libtorrent libxml2 libxslt libyaml lxml m2crypto markupsafe midistream msgpack mysql_connector netifaces numpy opencv openssl paramiko pil plyer plyvel png polygon protobuf psutil psycopg2 pyasn1 pycrypto pygame pyjnius pylibpd pyopenssl pyparsing pyqrcode python pyyaml sdl setuptools six sqlalchemy sqlite3 storm swift thrift twisted txws werkzeug wokkel zeroconf zope
# Remove directory and subdirectory /home/kivy/Documents/kbs/.buildozer/applibs
# Create directory /home/kivy/Documents/kbs/.buildozer/applibs
# Run 'bash -c "source venv/bin/activate && env"'
# Cwd /home/kivy/Documents/kbs/.buildozer
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
XDG_MENU_PREFIX=xfce-
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
GDM_LANG=en_US
DISPLAY=:0.0
ANDROIDAPI=19
GTK_OVERLAY_SCROLLING=0
COLORTERM=truecolor
XDG_VTNR=7
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
VIRTUAL_ENV=/home/kivy/Documents/kbs/.buildozer/venv
MANDATORY_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/xubuntu.mandatory.path
GLADE_CATALOG_PATH=:
XDG_SESSION_ID=c2
XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR=/var/lib/lightdm-data/kivy
USER=kivy
GLADE_MODULE_PATH=:
DESKTOP_SESSION=xubuntu
ANDROIDNDK=/home/kivy/.buildozer/crystax-ndk
DEFAULTS_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/xubuntu.default.path
QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=gtk2
PWD=/home/kivy/Documents/kbs/.buildozer
HOME=/home/kivy
ANDROIDSDK=/home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20
SSH_AGENT_PID=1309
QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/xubuntu:/usr/share/xfce4:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop:/usr/share
PACKAGES_PATH=/home/kivy/.buildozer/android/packages
XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=xubuntu
GLADE_PIXMAP_PATH=:
CLUTTER_BACKEND=x11
VTE_VERSION=4402
SHELL=/bin/bash
TERM=xterm-256color
XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=XFCE
QT_LINUX_ACCESSIBILITY_ALWAYS_ON=1
SHLVL=2
XDG_SEAT=seat0
LANGUAGE=en_US:
ANDROIDNDKVER=r9c
WINDOWID=67112367
GDMSESSION=xubuntu
LOGNAME=kivy
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
XAUTHORITY=/home/kivy/.Xauthority
XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0
XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-xubuntu:/etc/xdg:/etc/xdg
PATH=/home/kivy/Documents/kbs/.buildozer/venv/bin:/home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
PS1=(venv) 
SESSION_MANAGER=local/kivyvm:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1327,unix/kivyvm:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1327
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
_=/usr/bin/env
# Install distribute
# Run 'curl http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py | venv/bin/python'
# Cwd /home/kivy/Documents/kbs/.buildozer
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:02:10 --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to python-distribute.org port 80: Connection timed out
# Install requirement python3crystax in virtualenv
# Run 'pip install --target=/home/kivy/Documents/kbs/.buildozer/applibs python3crystax'
# Cwd /home/kivy/Documents/kbs/.buildozer
Collecting python3crystax
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python3crystax (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for python3crystax
# Command failed: pip install --target=/home/kivy/Documents/kbs/.buildozer/applibs python3crystax
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

And here's my questions:
  1)What is python3crystax literally? Is a pip package, utility, file or what?
  2)Must i download python3crystax manually and where i can to download this?
  3)What i did wrong?

UPD:
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40470825/kivy-buildozer-cant-compile-application-targeting-python3?rq=1) question and tried `buildozer -v android_new debug`
Got this (log_level in buildozer.spec is 2):

```
# Check configuration tokens
# Ensure build layout
# Check configuration tokens
# Preparing build
# Check requirements for android
# Run 'dpkg --version'
# Cwd None
Debian 'dpkg' package management program version 1.18.10 (amd64).
This is free software; see the GNU General Public License version 2 or
later for copying conditions. There is NO warranty.
# Search for Git (git)
#  -> found at /usr/bin/git
# Search for Cython (cython)
#  -> found at /usr/local/bin/cython
# Search for Java compiler (javac)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
# Search for Java keytool (keytool)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/keytool
# Install platform
# Apache ANT found at /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4
# Android SDK found at /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20
# Android NDK found at /home/kivy/.buildozer/crystax-ndk
# Check application requirements
# Check garden requirements
# Compile platform
# Run 'python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain --color=always --storage-dir=/home/kivy/Documents/kbs/.buildozer/android/platform/build create --dist_name=cyapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3crystax,kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs'
# Cwd /home/kivy/Documents/kbs/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master
[INFO]:    Will compile for the following archs: armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    Found Android API target in $ANDROIDAPI
[INFO]:    Available Android APIs are (19)
[INFO]:    Requested API target 19 is available, continuing.
[INFO]:    Found NDK dir in $ANDROIDNDK
[INFO]:    Got NDK version from $ANDROIDNDKVER
[WARNING]: NDK version was set as r10.3.2, but checking the NDK dir claims it is 10.3.2.
[WARNING]: The build will try to continue, but it may fail and you should check that your setting is correct.
[WARNING]: If the NDK dir result is correct, you don't need to manually set the NDK ver.
[INFO]:    Using Crystax NDK r10.3.2
[INFO]:    Found virtualenv at /usr/local/bin/virtualenv
[INFO]:    ccache is missing, the build will not be optimized in the future.
[WARNING]: include directory doesn't exist: /home/kivy/.buildozer/crystax-ndk/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi
[INFO]:    Found the following toolchain versions: ['4.9', '5', 'clang3.6', 'clang3.7']
[INFO]:    Picking the latest gcc toolchain, here 5
[WARNING]: Missing executable: autoconf is not installed
[WARNING]: Missing executable: automake is not installed
[WARNING]: Missing executable: libtoolize is not installed
[ERROR]:   python-for-android cannot continue; aborting
# Command failed: python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain --color=always --storage-dir=/home/kivy/Documents/kbs/.buildozer/android/platform/build create --dist_name=cyapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3crystax,kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

I see some weird string in logs. I really have not this path in Crystax ndk folder.

```
[WARNING]: include directory doesn't exist: /home/kivy/.buildozer/crystax-ndk/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Download and extract the [Crystax NDK](https://www.crystax.net/en/download) somewhere e.g. /opt/
2. Make sure the following lines are in your buildozer.spec file.:

   ### Require python3crystax:

   requirements = python3crystax,kivy

   ### Point to the directory where you extracted the crystax-ndk:

   android.ndk_path = /opt/crystax-ndk-10.3.2

Comment: i did these actions... My Crystax ndk folder placed in .buildozer folder (/home/kivy/.buildozer). And my buildozer.spec : android.ndk_path = ~/.buildozer/crystax-ndk  . Also i tried /home/kivy/.buildozer/crystax-ndk , same error

Comment: Edit your buildozer.spec and replace `log_level = 1' with `log_level = 2`. Rerun `buildozer android_new debug`

Comment: Ignore the warnings. Please share the latest debug log.

Comment: Log_level = 2, yes? Output logs didn't changed, it is the same as i posted in UPD section.